# Constrain a regex match's starting point

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing a long string and want to use a regular expression for part of the parsing.

For simplicity, let's say my regex is `<[a-z]*>` and I'd like to run it when I get to the first `<`.

```
public int FindEnd(string longStr, int index) {
    // longStr[index] == '<'

    var match = regex.Match(longStr, index);
    if (!match.Success || match.Index != index) {
        throw new Exception("Mismatch");
    } else {
        return index + match.Length;
    }
}
```

I'd like to constrain the regex somehow so that it doesn't go over the entire string, but only looks for strings at the given starting point - is this possible? I tried `^<[a-z]*>` but that didn't work - it wouldn't accept anything (except if `index` points to the start of the string).

<sub>Note: I'm *not* trying to [parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `\G<[a-z]*>`

Comment: Excellent! This did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pity Regex.Match(String, Int32) doesn't treat the index as "^".

What about kludging it with something like this:

re = new Regex( "^.{" + index.ToString() + "}<[a-z]*>" );

...that is to say, constrain the offset of the start of the match within the regex itself.

UPDATE: Oh. Never mind. MSDN's description of "\G" mentions a "previous match", but it works precisely as described above. Much better solution than mine.

Comment: I already know that `longStr[index] == '<'` before I call this method; I want the regex to not match when I call it on the first `<` in the following string though: `a<b<c>d`.

Comment: /<[a-z]*>/ will not match the substring including the first "<" in "a<b<c>d". Oh, no, wait, now I get it. Hmm...

Comment: It's a pity that Regex.Match(String s, Int32 i) does not treat s[i] as "^". It's one of those times when I get homesick for the STL.